# Magento: assign product (grouped) category to all simple product that build it

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have 8000 **simple products** without category assigned.

These simple products are used to create a lot some **grouped products**.

All grouped product have category assigned.

Is possible to assign grouped product category to all simple products that are associated to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just try to add entries to `catalog_category_product` table..:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_category_product (category_id, product_id)
SELECT ccp.category_id, cpr.child_id FROM catalog_product_entity  cpe
JOIN catalog_product_relation cpr ON cpr.parent_id = cpe.entity_id
JOIN catalog_category_product ccp ON cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id
WHERE cpe.type_id = 'grouped'
ORDER BY cpe.entity_id
;
```

following SQL will add all simple products which are associated with any grouped products to all categories to which the grouped product is assigned. I wrote in just now and didn't test it so be sure to test it before launching on PRODUCTION db;-)